# Can the weapon master feat give proficiency with firearms?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, proficiency, firearms

The feat gives proficiency with 4 simple or martial weapons of your choice. From what I understand the renaissance firearm weapons in the DMG are classified as ranged martial weapons. So, could this feat be used to give proficiency with say, a pistol?

Also, I know the gunner feat exists. The idea is to get proficiency with the double-bladed scimitar as well on a swashbuckler.

Edit: Please note that firearms are present in my game. Also, I am not trying to get proficiency with firearms or martial weapons. Much like how the rogue says you can get proficiency with simple weapons as well as a select few listed martial weapons, I am trying to get proficiency in a pistol.

Comment: I'm guessing we should assume there are firearms in your game? Also, what does firearm proficiency do for double-bladed scimitars?

Comment: @Naut They want to use Weapon Master to get both proficiencies at once

Comment: Related, possible dupe: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/158879/62294

Comment: It is related but the post you linked does not definitely answer the question. However, thank you for sharing! @ThomasMarkov

Answer (score 6):

#### Only if the DM allows it to.

The rules for proficiency with firearms state:

> *It’s up to you [the DM] to decide whether a character has proficiency with a firearm.* Characters in most D&D worlds wouldn’t have such proficiency. During their downtime, characters can use the training rules in the Player’s Handbook to acquire proficiency, assuming that they have enough ammunition to keep the weapons working while mastering their use.

A character cannot choose to take firearm proficiency without the DM's permission. Being a martial weapon is not enough to qualify a firearm for the feat, you still need the DM's permission. The fighter class gets proficiency with all martial weapons, but does not get proficiency with firearms. Ergo, a feature that grants proficiency with martial weapons does not grant proficiency with firearms, unless the DM allows it to.